# Specifying Directories during Fortran Compilation

Tags: directory, fortran, gnu, gfortran, opensuse

I am using GNU Fortran 95 on OpenSUSE Leap to compile my source code, and I am trying to figure out how to tell gfortran to change the default directory to search for my modules.

Let me explain my setup. I've written several module files that contain general subroutines I use. I've placed and compiled these files in a folder entitled ModuleRepo. My working scripts are placed in a separate folder. For example, I tried the following command:

```
gfortran -o script script.f95 -I/pathToFolder/ModuleRepo module1.o module2.o
```

However, this is not working. It is returning the following error:

```
gfortran: error: module1.o: No such file or directory.
```

The *.o files do exist in ModuleRepo, so I'm unsure what's going on. Everything works fine if I copy all my module files to the directory. But, I'd like a way to avoid copying the same files over and over.

Comment: Also, I tried finding examples of the -I option online, but was unsuccessful. I know there are also the -J and -fintrinsic-module-path options, but I wasn't able to use those properly either. As with the -I option, I was unable to find examples for these options.

Comment: Generally .o files are object files not module files (.mod).  Do you have those latter?

Comment: I do. I just knew that the normal command I would use to compile would be

gfortran -o script script.f95 module1.o module2.o

As such, I figured it would be the same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gfortran -o script script.f95 -I/pathToFolder/ModuleRepo /pathToFolder/ModuleRepo/module1.o /pathToFolder/ModuleRepo/module2.o
```

Comment: When I run that piece of code, it returns the following:

use randommodule
     1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'randommodule.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory

Comment: But, the file randommodule.mod is absolutely there.

Comment: Ok, specify the path to the include directory as well to access the .mod files

Comment: What do you mean by the include directory?

Comment: Forgive me, I just saw the changes you made. This worked well. Thank you!